# what is the of the % next to images on git push?

Tags: git, github

I've always wondered what the percent next to image rewrites means when you make a `git push`

example:

`rewrite assets/img/30_credits.png (70%)`

I've always assumed it simply shows how much of the Image canvas has been rewritten, though I'd love to know for definite.

Sorry for the silly question :) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: this is Git's *similarity index*.  For a detailed description of the algorithm for computing similarity, see [Trying to understand `git diff` and `git mv` rename detection mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46256139/1256452).

Longer:  This actually isn't `git push`; you saw this from `git pull`.  But it isn't `git pull` either: it's output resulting from `git pull` running `git merge`, and it is actually `git diff --stat` that prints it.<sup>1</sup>  What `git diff --stat` prints here is:<sup>2</sup>

`verb path (percentage)`

where *`verb`* is one of `rename`, `rewrite`, or `copy`, *`path`* is a file path name or abbreviated version of the same or (for renames) old and new path names, and *percentage* is the similarity index.  Git uses this similarity index to determine whether two files with different names, or two files with the same name but very different contents, might actually be the *same* file, or *different* files after all.

That is, suppose commit `ba3c046` has files `A1.txt` and `A2.txt` in it, and commit `50fcdab` has `A2.txt` and `B1.txt` in it (and neither commit has any other files).  It's *likely*—it stands to reason—that the two `A2.txt` files are "the same" file, even if the contents are somewhat changed.  Perhaps someone checked out commit `ba3c046` and modified the file and then made commit `50fcdab` from the modified result.

But what about `A1.txt` vs `B1.txt`?  Maybe someone checked out `ba3c046`, *renamed* the file—with or without changing it—and made commit `50fcdab`.  If they did, commit `50fcdab`'s `B1.txt` is really the same file as commit `ba3c046`'s `A1.txt`.

The way Git determines if these two are really identical files, or "nearly identical" (renamed and slightly changed) files, is to compare them for similarity.  To do so, it computes the similarity index between `A1.txt` and `B1.txt`.

Now suppose that we're comparing commit `ba3c046` (with its two files) to commit `0f3ac31`, which has `A2.txt`, `B1.txt`, and `C1.txt`.  It doesn't matter to Git when each commit was made; Git will look at the contents in `A1.txt` and score their similarity to `0f3ac31`'s `B1.txt` *and* `0f3ac31`'s `C1.txt`.  If the file is sufficiently similar, Git will match it up.  Git will pick the `0f3ac31` file that is *most similar* to the `A1.txt` in `ba3c046`.

This process—of matching up files by how close their *contents* match—is how Git determines which files are "the same" in the two commits being `git diff`-ed.  The term I have been using for this process is *identifying files*, which I don't like as well as I might since we're not trying to find files that are *100%* identical (although it helps a *lot* when they are, due to Git's internal storage system).

By default, two files in two different commits are automatically identified (as "the same file") if they have the same name, even if their contents differ a whole lot.  That is, these two files are pre-paired, rather than being paired up because of a computed similarity.  In this case, their *similarity index* will be relatively poor, and Git will call that a "rewrite".

Git also has a *dissimilarity index* concept, which is just 100 minus the similarity: files 75% similar are 25% dissimilar, for instance.  The `-B` (break pairings) flag to `git diff` can be used to break the automatic pairings from Git's default assumption, that a file whose path is *P* in the left-side commit must be identical to the file whose path is *P* in the right-side commit.  Running `git merge` invokes `git diff` without setting the break flag, though.

Calculating similarity is expensive, so it's done only for unpaired files or under -B`.  The unpaired files are those without a partner on the other side initially, or those broken-apart by`-B`.  If you use the`-C`or`--find-copies`or`--find-copies-harder` options, Git will consider some left-hand / source-side files as perhaps having been *copied* to some right-hand / destination-side files, so that pairing a source side file with a destination side file does not remove the source file from the "sources" pool.  For a large repository where the two sides of the diff contain a lot of files, this requires doing a lot of similarity computations, and can take a lot of time.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can also get a similarity index from `git apply`.  I think the diffstat output from `git merge` is now built directly into `git merge` itself, but for a real merge, you can repeat it by running `git diff --stat <merge>^1 <merge>`.

For a fast-forward operation (which isn't really a merge even though `git merge` will do it) you need to specify the correct pair of commits.  Right after `git pull`, this is `HEAD@{1}` and `HEAD`, so `git diff --stat HEAD@{1} HEAD` will do the trick, but since these are relative names, they will stop working after a while.)  Also, a few shells (PowerShell on Windows, and tcsh and zsh on Linux, for instance) make it harder to provide the `@{1}` suffix as they like to use the `{...}` syntax for their own purposes.

<sup>2</sup>There are several formats for this.  The output from `git diff-tree`, for instance, uses code letters and percentages, rather than words.  These are all just different ways to say the same thing, though: that Git has paired up certain files in the left and right side commits, perhaps despite some changes to those files' contents.

Comment: What a brilliant answer! Thank you so much :) Even if I did have to read it multiple times to digest it, haha! Your first paragraph gave me a bit of a giggle too. I've never really gone out of my way to understand the underlying mechanics of Git, I don't think many have, actually. So it's nice to get some more info. Once again, thank you!