# How to map files between two repositories in GIT?

Tags: git, gitlab

Imagine there is a GIT repository and I forked it to do custom features on it. As such, I have to relocate some files, yet maintain the reference of that file to the original repository so that if there are any updates happened I can merge it in mine without manual work

[image].

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is natively supported by Git or GitLab.

You would need a script to:

- fetch from the original repo
- rename the files (and change their content to reflect the new package name) in a dedicated branch
- merge that dedicated branch with yours in order to get the original repository file modifications.

Comment: plus, I believe modern Git versions can track changesets across renamed files.

Comment: @NilsWerner Yes, through the similarity index (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46258968/6309)