# In the git format-patch statement, what does the -M switch do?

Tags: git

Consider the following `git` statement:

`git format-patch -M origin/master`

Chacon and Straub state in their book "Pro Git", 2.1:

> The -M switch tells Git to look for renames.

1. What does the `-M` switch do?

2. In this context, what are "renames"?

Comment: [`git help format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch#Documentation/git-format-patch.txt--Mltngt)

Comment: @phd, Thanks. I had read this before posting, but it is still not clear.

Comment: Esp. with question "*what are "renames"?*"

Comment: @phd, _What_ is being renamed? A variable? A constant?

Comment: Git doesn't work with variables or constants. Git works with commits and files. Commits cannot be renamed. There are also branches and tags; they can be renamed but they're second-class citizens and are not used with `format-patch`.

Comment: @phd, OK. Therefore, does it mean that _files_ are being renamed and that is what the -M switch identifies?

Comment: Yes. Please read about rename detection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46258968/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+rename+detection

Comment: @phd,, Thanks for the clarification. Problem solved.