# Git renamed files and inodes

Tags: git, file-rename

Consider that we apply the following commands, to a file (`hello.txt`) tracked under git (in a clean working copy):

```
echo "hi" >> hello.txt
mv hello.txt bye.txt
git rm hello.txt
git add bye.txt
git status
```

**Result:**

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    renamed:    hello.txt -> bye.txt
```

So, git knows it is the same file, even though it was renamed.
I had some vague memory, that git checks inodes to determine that the new file is the same as the old deleted files.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7941544/3398271) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822823/how-does-git-know-that-file-was-renamed?noredirect=1&lq=1) SO answer, though, suggest that git only checks the **contents** of the file, and does not in any way check that it is the same inode. (My conclusion (*): if I did bigger modifications to the file, git would not detect the rename, even though the inode was still the same.)

It seemed to me thus quite obvious, that I was wrong, and git does not check inodes (or any other file-system info at all), just the contents. But then, I found [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4075667/3398271), which claims that

> In addition to the timestamp, it [i.e., git] records the size, inode, and other
>   information from lstat to reduce the chance of a false positive. When
>   you perform git-status, it simply calls lstat on every file in the
>   working tree and compares the metadata in order to quickly determine
>   which files are unchanged.

**I actually have two questions about this:**

1. Is my understanding below correct?

*Git does rely (also) on inodes to detect if a file was changed, but it does NOT use inodes to detect file renames.*

2. Assuming 1. is correct. Why does git not rely on inodes to detect file renames?
   If it did, then we would not have the problem above, marked with (*). (I.e., it would detect the rename, no matter how big the content change.)

(I imagine that the answer is something like "so that the behaviour is the same on system that don't have inodes, e.g. Windows". However, if that's the case, then this "same behaviour" was already broken by relying on inodes for detecting changes.)

Comment: You're assuming that (*) is a _problem_.  Git doesn't consider it a problem, it's by design.

Comment: @EdwardThomson: what is the **benefit** of this behaviour from the git-user perspective?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full answer is complicated, but there's no cause for concern here.  There is one real problem, which I'll get to at the end, but it has nothing to do with inodes.

Let's start with a side trip to discuss—as briefly as I can and still remain stand-alone—Git's `HEAD`, index, and work-tree.  Let's look briefly at the file/object storage model as well.  Then, let's talk about `git diff`, and then about `git status`.  Then we'll be ready to look at how the index works as a cache, and where inodes come in.  Last, we'll be ready to see how the real problem occurs.

Up here, though, I'll insert this summary:  **Normally, this is all completely invisible.  The cached data are correct and the second `git diff` that `git status` runs goes fast.  Or, the cached data are out of date, Git notices that the cached data are out of date, and the second `git diff` goes slower and—as a side effect—updates whatever cached data it can, so that another `git diff` run by another `git status` will go fast.**  So, normally, you don't have to care about any of this.

---

#### `HEAD`, the index, and the work-tree

The work-tree is, of course, simply a tree of files in their ordinary (non-Git) format, where you and all the code on your computer can work with them.  Initially, you clone a repository and/or run `git checkout branch` and your work-tree is now filled with the files that correspond to some branch tip, such as `master` or *`branch`*.  You can also run `git checkout hash` or similar to get what GIt calls a "detached HEAD"; in this case the current commit is some historical commit, but as before, your work-tree is filled with the files that correspond to that commit.  (There are some exceptions to this rule: for instance, you can have *untracked files;* and see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).)

The `HEAD` commit is, by definition, the current commit.  As with every other commit, this commit is read-only; it has some metadata (author and committer, parent commit hash, and commit message); and it stores a tree object hash ID, by which it stores (indirectly) a complete snapshot of files.  Since this is the current commit, it's also—initially at least, and there are various special cases that can interfere here—what you will see in your work-tree.  Note that all the files *in* the current commit are not just read-only, like everything inside the object database; they are also in a special Git-only format.  Few if any non-Git commands can read these files at all.

Between the `HEAD` and work-tree, though, there's a point where Git deviates rather radically from other version control systems like Mercurial and Subversion.  Git exposes—and in fact *forces* you to know about—Git's *index*, also called the *staging-area* and the *cache*.  This index really does, at least figuratively, stand right between the `HEAD` and the work-tree.  The `HEAD` (current commit) contains a snapshot of files in a special Git-only form.  The work-tree contains all your files in ordinary form.  If we put `HEAD` on the left and the work-tree on the right, the index occupies the space in between.  If you're in a new repository with just a README file committed, you might have this rather silly looking situation:

```
 HEAD     index     w.tree
------    ------    ------
README    README    README
```

The `README` in `HEAD` is read-only.  It's in special Git form.  You can't change it.

The `README` in the index is also in special Git form, but it's read/write: you *can* change it.  You can't actually *use* it at all though, because it's in that special Git-only form.

The `README` in your work-tree is in ordinary (non-Git) form.  It's read/write: you can do whatever you want with it.  *Git* can't use it yet though, because it's *not* in the special Git-only form.

The full purpose of the index is complicated, but the short version of it—before we get into inodes at all—is that it's *where you build the next commit you will make.*  If you want to *change* the `README`, or add a *new* file, you can first make the change in your work-tree.  Let's say you change `README` and create a new (as yet untracked) `a.txt`:

```
 HEAD     index     w.tree
------    ------    ------
README-   README-   README+
                    a.txt
```

For the purpose of this diagram I've labeled the two variants of `README` with `-` (the old one) and `+` (the new one).  The new, modified `README` is *only in your work-tree*.

If you now were to run `git add README`, this would *copy* the work-tree `README` into the special Git-only format, and put that into the index.  If, instead, you run `git add a.txt`, that will *copy* the work-tree `a.txt` into the special Git-only format and put that into the index.  The end result is:

```
 HEAD     index     w.tree
------    ------    ------
README-   README-   README+
          a.txt     a.txt
```

If you now run `git commit`—without first running `git add README`—Git will now make a *new* commit from whatever is in the index *right now*.  That's the old `README` and the new `a.txt`.  This new commit becomes the current (`HEAD`) commit, so now we have:

```
 HEAD     index     w.tree
------    ------    ------
README-   README-   README+
a.txt     a.txt     a.txt
```

If you now run `git add README`, the index will get the new version of `README`; committing that will make a new `HEAD` commit with the new `README` so that everything matches:

```
 HEAD     index     w.tree
------    ------    ------
README    README    README
a.txt     a.txt     a.txt
```

In each case, `git commit` just takes whatever is in the index *right then* and turns it into a frozen, read-only snapshot for the new commit.  Since the files are already in the special Git-only format, this goes very fast.  That's one of the tricks Git uses to get its speed: the slow part, converting from plain format to special compressed Git format, happens during `git add`, not during `git commit`.  If you have millions of files, but only modified two or three, Git never has to re-compress all the millions of files.

#### File and object storage

Let's look at the way that Git stores commits and files, which Git calls *blobs*, and its other two intermediate object types, which Git calls *trees* and *annotated tags*.  There are multiple levels of compression that Git can use on these data, but we won't go into any of that; we'll just look at how Git uses hash IDs.

What Git does with all four of these things—which Git calls *objects*—is to reduce them all to a cryptographic checksum (currently SHA-1 but moving to a new checksum eventually).  Git prepends the object type—`commit`, `tree`, `blob`, or `tag` and the size in bytes, and calculates the hash.  The result is guaranteed to be unique (see also [How does the newly found sha1 collision affect git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452)).  Git uses this as the key in a [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-value_database) to stuff the (compressed) data into the repository database.  Git can thus extract the object data quickly given the key.

What this means for us is that within a commit (as identified by its unique hash ID), each file is really stored as just a <name, ID> pair.  (More correctly, it's a <mode, name, ID> triple.  This is also true within the index, although there, Git stores even more data.)  This makes it really easy to tell if a file is completely unchanged: if it is, it has the same hash ID, because the same input data always reduce to the same hash ID.

Since the actual *contents* are in the key-value store under the ID, the commit can just list the ID.  If thousands of commits list `README` or `a.txt` with the same ID, the actual file is stored only once, under the ID; each commit stores just the ID.

Of course, if one commit has one version of `README` with one ID, and another commit has a different version of `README`, the two commits will have two different IDs for the file named `README`.

#### `git diff` and rename detection

There are a lot of nitty details about `git diff`—some of which will hit us in just a moment—but let's ignore them for now and concentrate instead on how `git diff` works when you give it two particular commits.  Git can look up both commits, obtain their stored snapshot trees, and compare IDs.  *Any IDs that match mean the files match, so `git diff` only has to look at files that have different IDs.*  This is an enormous time-saver.

Suppose we ask Git to compare commit/tree *L* (left) vs commit/tree *R* (right), and every file *except* for `README` has the same ID.  That is, *L*'s `a.txt` has ID `12345...` and its `b.dat` has ID `6789a...`, but *L*'s `README` is `ccccc...`.  *R*'s `a.txt` also is `12345...` and its `b.dat` is also `6789a...`, but *R*'s `README` is `eeeee...`.  Git is only really going to have to extract the two `README` blobs (files `ccccc...` and `eeeee...`) and compare those two blobs to produce context diffs.

Now suppose that we have Git compare two trees, and everything is the same between *L* and *R* except that *L* has a file named `README` and *R* has a file named `README.md`.  Was the file renamed?  It could have been!  Git can, first, compare the two hashes.  If they match exactly, the file was certainly renamed.  If they don't match exactly, Git can extract the two blobs and compare them for similarity.  If they seem pretty similar (say, 97% similar), Git can *assume* the file was renamed.

That, in a nutshell, is how `git diff` does rename detection: take the tree on the left *L* and the tree on the right *R*.  All the files that exist in both *L* and *R* are either "the same" or "modified".  Files that *were* in *L* but *aren't* in *R*, can maybe be matched up with files that are *only* in *R*.  First do a fast check of their hashes and pair up exact matches.  Then, do a similarity scan on everything that's left, and pair up those that are sufficiently similar: they were renamed (and maybe modified slightly too).  Any remaining files that are gone from *L* or new in *R* were deleted or newly-added.

#### Making `git diff` fast is a problem with the work-tree

The scheme outlined above works great with actual commits, because files inside commits are in that special, Git-only form.  It even works with the index, because files in the index are *also* in special, Git-only form: they've already been reduced to hash IDs.  The index, in this case, acts like a flattened tree.  The work-tree, alas, is *not* in the special, Git-only form.  We'll come back to this soon, because....

#### The `git status` command just runs two `git diff`s

When you run `git status`, Git runs two internal diffs.  The first one compares `HEAD` vs the index.  This is very fast for the reason we saw above: everything is already in this ideal format, with files reduced to unique hash IDs.  Git can scan `HEAD` as *L* and the index as *R*, and compute the diff very quickly.  (Since we don't care about the changes themselves—just about which files are the same, which are renamed, and which are modified—Git can omit the slowest part of most such diffs, which is computing the context diff to print.)

Alas, the second diff is much slower: Git must compare the index vs the work-tree.  The work-tree is not in special Git-only format.  Git *could* make a second, temporary index and add everything to it, but this would be very slow, so it doesn't do that.  To make this diff much faster, Git secretly adds *cache* data to the index, and this is where the inodes come in.  The inode numbers are part of this cached data.  But this is (normally, at least; see below) just a speed hack.  If the inode numbers change, `git status` is simply *slower*.

#### The index as cache

In those earlier diagrams showing `HEAD`, the index, and the work-tree, notice how it was so common to have all three files exactly the same, or—once we modify a file in the work-tree and then `git add` it—to have the index match the work-tree.  What if there were some way that Git could know, quickly, whether a work-tree file had been changed *since* an earlier time when Git looked very closely at the work-tree file knew for sure that it was, or wasn't, exactly the same as the index version?

It turns out that while there is no perfect method for this, there's a method that's good enough (at least in most people's valuations).  Git can use the OS's `lstat` system call on each work-tree file and save, in the index, some of the data from the call (part but not all of ctime, mtime, ino, mode, uid, gid, and size, per the [index format documentation in the technical notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt)).  If the data in a later `lstat` call match that from an earlier one, the work-tree file is assumed to have the same in-file data as before.

The exact usefulness of this data are a bit tricky.  Some of the stored data are used to decide whether a work-tree file is "clean", i.e., matches the version in the index.  [There is a one-second granularity issue and a race condition](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/racy-git.txt) where Git may have to assume, temporarily, that a work-tree file is *not* clean, and then do an expensive *clean* operation on the file to find out whether it's really clean or not.  **Note, however, that the general case is that Git simply does extra work, i.e., slows down to check whether a file that is clean should be considered clean.  It does not cause Git to consider a file clean when it's actually dirty.**  The one case that could fool the detector here occurs when you manage to set *both* the mtime and ctime back while keeping the (low 32 bits of the) size the same, but doing so generally requires re-setting the computer's clock as well.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>This is because the system calls that alter the mtime to any value you choose, all set the ctime to "now" where "now" is taken from the system clock.   Hence, to set the mtime to (e.g.) yesterday while also setting the ctime to yesterday, you must first set the system itself to yesterday.

---

#### The one real problem

There's a more significant problem, though, that really does show up in real repositories.  Suppose the index's cache attributes tell you that a work-tree file is clean, i.e., the work-tree version matches the index version of the file.  Suppose also that you are making use of `.gitattributes` with clean and smudge filters, or with end of line conversions.  In this case, copying a file from the index to the work-tree applies the smudge filter:

```
read-from-index :0:$path | $smudge > $path
```

(where `read-from-index` is a somewhat hypothetical program that is actually implemented by `git cat-file -p`, `$smudge` is your filter for this file, and `$path` is the path name you want for the file—the `:0:` is the special syntax Git uses for "index slot zero").

Meanwhile, copying files from the work-tree to the index applies the clean filter:

```
$clean < $path | write-to-index $path
```

(where `write-to-index` can be written using `git update-index`; you also need to supply the mode and stage number).

The problem comes in two parts:

- **the filters chosen for `$clean` and `$smudge` depend on end of line conversion selection, `.gitattributes` contents, and your configuration**; and
- **the actions taken by `$clean` and `$smudge` are not under Git's control**.

If Git determines that a file is "clean" based on its stat and index data, but you *change* which `$clean` filter is applied, or what `$clean` does, then re-cleaning the file and writing the result to the index would produce *different index data*.  In other words, ***even though the index's cache attributes proclaim that the file is clean, it's actually dirty.***

Where this typically shows up is when you add line-ending changes to your configuration and/or edit `.gitattributes` to change which files get line-ending changes applied.  **Note that if you never have Git touch line endings, this is never a problem.**

There are two remedies, one that works en-masse by removing and recreating the index, and a simpler one:

- If you know you have not staged any files, you can remove the index file (`.git/index`) and run `git reset` (which does a `--mixed` reset, re-creating the index from `HEAD`).  If you *have* staged files and hit this problem, you can still use this remedy, you just need to re-stage.  If you've carefully staged *parts* of some files you don't want to use this method, but you can use the simpler one-file-at-a-time remedy.
- If you just want to force Git to consider some file `$path` as dirty, update its modification time to "now", e.g.:

  ```
  $ touch $path
  ```

  Now the file is marked dirty and Git will be forced to run whatever the currently-defined cleaning process is, before seeing whether the file is clean.

Comment: If you have no unmerged index entries, then you can use `git read-tree $(git write-tree)`.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the in depth answer, I learned a lot! Is my understanding now correct?  "1. Git does rely (also) on inodes to detect if a file was changed, but it does NOT use inodes to detect file renames." --> true, it first compares `lstat` of the work-tree file (which includes inode) with the cached values, and if they are different, it compares the content. "2. Why does git not rely on inodes to detect file renames?" --> because git uses the whole `lstat` and parts of it (timestamps) do change upon a rename.

Comment: 1 is true enough: it falls out of the general rule that "if something in the cached inode stats have changed, we must take a more detailed look to see if things *really* changed". 2 isn't required: Git wants to detect renames of files that don't match 100%, and to do it in situations in which there are no inodes involved, such as when comparing two commits that are ultimately stored in pack files. If "is renamed" is independent of the very existence of inodes, it can't depend on fields within inodes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing here two a bit different concepts:

- git storage
- git client behaviour

**First** about internal **storage of files in git**.
In short: when files are stored in git there are no reference to inodes and diffs at all.

As you know git operates on tree of commits. Each commit has reference to a tree (similar in its meaning to directory in a filesystem):

```
$ git cat-file commit HEAD  # example for some random git repo on my disk
tree e68e0f9afad22357e47d0a341770f2315ee16b2c
parent 6d13fea5d0c1d0b4aedf96b7141c05c73bf9c9cb
author Timur Batyrshin <erthad@gmail.com> 1590062438 +0300
committer Timur Batyrshin <erthad@gmail.com> 1590062438 +0300

add icon to the workflow
```

Here `e68e0f9afad22357e47d0a341770f2315ee16b2c` is a hash referencing tree object attached to this commit. You can browse its contents:

```
$ git ls-tree e68e0f9afad22357e47d0a341770f2315ee16b2c
100644 blob 2dd98d7ddcdb1c24d5fa368c349614baec840167    .gitignore
100644 blob 71cf7988bc6ca7e38fbb8d0490cb0b9f2368d3dc    LICENSE
100644 blob 67ed24d3dd5ed71a9b03180d0540276c659e71c3    README.md
100644 blob 5ab2fb346e9bf27d048bad4725ae1180a0d1fffc    icon.png
100644 blob 198e0a4a3df7eedc752643d1a7d21b825ff5f2b2    info.plist
100755 blob 9969b7006112d4d25a7af472cd63ba61e6fd3736    login.sh
100755 blob 834e97824d38849d9254aa4607e636dc5ef7bae4    populate.sh
100755 blob 48bf586e84f820c1434959e8064fe8331a0ff5e3    show.rb
```

As you see the trees in git store file name, file mode (similar to unix file mode albeit a bit different) and a reference to binary blob storing the contents of this file.
For example here is the first 3 lines of the contents of `.gitignore` file from that specific commit which has hash `2dd98d7ddcdb1c24d5fa368c349614baec840167`:

```
$ git cat-file blob 2dd98d7ddcdb1c24d5fa368c349614baec840167 | head -n 3
*.gem
*.rbc
/.config
```

**To summarize**: each git commit points to a tree object. Tree objects in turn point to specific blobs with file contents (or to other subtrees).

Git storage has no references to diffs and no references to inodes.

Git storage has even no references to renames: different trees point to different blobs and when you need diff git client just compares the 2 blobs and produces diff for you. Humans usually interested to see renames so git produces that info for you as well. I guess initially it displayed renames only when the file name referencing the same blob became different in the next commit and started to show small diffs as renames a few versions later.

Now to the **second** part: **git client behaviour**. Git is able to traverse the history and tree structure very fast but when you browse diffs git client has to calculate every single diff you need and it can be very time consuming in large repositories.

For this reason git clients usually employ various caching mechanisms and other means to speed up the process. This can be caching of file stats, comparing inodes and whatever else you could think of. The @torek's answer very well describes the problem and the approach for that.