# After git add, why are files 'renamed'?

Tags: git

In Git bash, I deleted a folder using:

```
GIT RM -r folder
```

Then I added a different folder using:

```
git add .
```

When I run git status, instead of "added", the new files have "renamed".
Note: The files and subfolders are almost identical.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Git know that file was renamed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822823/how-does-git-know-that-file-was-renamed)

Answer (score 0):

“The files and subfolders are almost identical.” Well that’s why. git sees this as a continuity; in effect you’ve merely moved the files, perhaps with some changes, to another folder. Usually that’s how people want this sort of thing to be understood by git.

Answer (score 0):

If a file has the *same* hash, it's considered the same file. So, even if you remove and recreate it, it's considered a rename.

And, in fact, I believe Git can *also* consider two files the same thing if they're only slightly different, based on how much changed in commits between the two actions (delete old and create new). Below a certain ratio, it considers it a rename-and-change rather than a delete-and-create.

What I take from this is that you shouldn't necessarily trust what Git is telling you. It's making a fairly educated guess as to what actually happened.